# retrofit2: java.io.EOFException even when Postman works fine

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2, okhttp, interceptor, eofexception

I'm trying to retrieve data from an API using an endpoint that works on Postman.
However, when I use it on Retrofit I get the EOFException. (using also interceptor to add a bearer token)

**MyInterface:**

```
   interface ITerminalAPIService {

    @GET("api/users/{UserId}")
    fun getUser(@Path("UserId")userId: Long): Call<User>
```

**myApi Provider:**

```
fun getRetrofitUser(context: Context, userId:Long) {
    val usersRetrofit = getRetrofit(context)
    val usersApiService = usersRetrofit.create(ITerminalAPIService::class.java)
    try {
        val apiUsers = usersApiService.getUser(userId)

        apiUsers.enqueue(object : Callback<User> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<User>,
                response: Response<User>
            ) {
                if (!response.isSuccessful) {
                    println("user response unsuccessful: ${response.code()}")
                }
                val user = response.body()
                /** do something with user*/

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<User>, t: Throwable) {
                t.printStackTrace()
            }
        })

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}


private fun getRetrofit(context: Context): Retrofit {
    val logInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    logInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    return Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BACKEND_URL)
        .client(
            OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                .connectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .addInterceptor(AuthInterceptor(context))
                .addInterceptor(logInterceptor)
                .build()
        )
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build()
}
```

**my intercept class:**

```
class AuthInterceptor(private val context: Context) : Interceptor {

override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
    var token: String? = null
    runBlocking {
        token = context.getSharedPreferences("Authenticate", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            .getString("Authenticate", "")
    }

    val newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
        .header("Authorization", "Bearer $token")
        .header("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
        .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
        .build()

    val response = chain.proceed(newRequest)

    if (response.code in 401..504) {
        //obtain additional data from response
        println("intercept ${response.code} code")
        println("intercept message: " + response.message)
        println("intercept Body: " + response.body)
    }
    return response
}
```

}

**here is the result:**

```
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: --> GET http://.../api/users/39365
    Authorization: Bearer eyJhb...
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Cache-Control: no-cache
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    --> END GET
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- 200 OK http://.../api/users/39365 (268ms)
    Date: Thu, 17 Dec 2020 18:14:02 GMT
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    Server: Kestrel
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Transfer-Encoding: chunked

W/System.err: java.io.EOFException
        at okio.RealBufferedSource.require(RealBufferedSource.kt:201)
W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSource.readHexadecimalUnsignedLong(RealBufferedSource.kt:400)
        at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec$ChunkedSource.readChunkSize(Http1ExchangeCodec.kt:429)
        at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec$ChunkedSource.read(Http1ExchangeCodec.kt:408)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange$ResponseBodySource.read(Exchange.kt:276)
        at okio.RealBufferedSource.request(RealBufferedSource.kt:207)
        at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.kt:245)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100)
        at pt.axians.ticketinspector.apicalls.interceptor.AuthInterceptor.intercept(AuthInterceptor.kt:26)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:197)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:502)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Consulting retrofit issues, I came across the following link: https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/2405
. However I do think that there might be a different issue because the endpoint works fine on Postman.

From Postman:
[image]

[image]

[image: Response Headers]

Comment: I will also try to add additional information, if usefull, from packeges cought using Wireshark (to compare data using Postman VS Retrofit)

Comment: Can you check if Postman is doing gzip? It might be a bug that only shows up with gzip.

Comment: The response "Content-Type" Header shows as "application/json; charset=utf-8"

Comment: Jesse Wilson, I had the chance to run the API directly in my computer (in this case using Visual Studio) and made the calls directly to it. I worked well, so this seems to be an issue not related to Retrofit but yes to the API itself and where it is running from. Thank you for your time and patience!